# PHP Script only works if browser is manually refreshed

Tags: php, r, google-search-console, php-ini

I'm using the following [PHP class to download website data from Google Webmaster Tools as CSV](https://github.com/eyecatchup/php-webmaster-tools-downloads). The class is called from another PHP file, which contains the class include along with the login information. This file is pretty straightforward:

```
<?php
    include 'gwtdata.php';
    try {
        $email = "username@gmail.com";
        $password = "******";

        # If hardcoded, don't forget trailing slash!
        $website = "http://www.domain.com/";

        $gdata = new GWTdata();
        if($gdata->LogIn($email, $password) === true)
        {
            $gdata->DownloadCSV($website);
        }
    } catch (Exception $e) {
        die($e->getMessage());
    }
```

However, it only downloads the CSV to the FTP server once I manually refresh my browser window, not when I open a new Tab and type the URL or I access the URL from another source, which is my biggest concern, as I am using R to call the URL and keep the data updated:

```
browseURL("URL", browser = "false")
```

I believe this should be a problem with the php.ini configuration, as the PHP script doesn't change at all. Do you know a way to bypass this behaviour?

Comment: Some caching issue perhaps? Does it work if you type the url and add a query variable like `?time=some_time_stamp`?

Comment: It might be that it sees your session as active and does not reset it. You can try force resetting your login info at every time the code is executed

Comment: @jeroen that did the trick. I am ashamed of not thinking about a caching issue.